# Markdown issue in private beta site

Tags: bug, design, private-beta

Today I visited the sign up page of Interpersonal Skills from a browser which I didn't signed in to Stack Exchange and saw a message,

> Warning: this site is currently in **private beta** for at least 1 more day.

I assume the double ** is used to indicate the private beta in bold text.

But it actually renders as

[image]

The same also happens in the Login message.